# converting suds to zeep failure

Tags: python, soap-client, suds, zeep

I replaced suds SOAP client with zeep's SOAP client, and I'm struggling to figure out several things.
1st: I had this code of suds client initialization:

```
 client.Client(
                wsdl_path,
                transport=suds_requests.RequestsTransport(session),
                plugins=[LogSOAPMessages()],
                cache=NoCache(),
                location="https://<serverIP>/MYWS/MYWSDispatch.pl"
            )
```

I'm struggling to understand how should I replace the 'location' kwarg in the zeep's client init function.

2nd: currently the new zeep's Client initialization is as described here:

```
Client(
                wsdl_path,
                transport=Transport(session=session),
                plugins=[LogSOAPMessages(), WsAddressingPlugin()]
            )
```

and the first API call to login looks like this:

```
client.service.authenticate(
                username=self.user,
                password=self.password,
            )
```

In suds it worked, but after replaced with zeep it raises this error:
`zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element MYWSHeader (authenticate.MYWSHeader)`,
but I can seem to find a solution or the reason to this new error.
why is it happening and how can I fix it?

*EDIT*: seems like adding MYWSHeader to the request solved the issue, for some reason it wasn't necessary in suds request, even though after inspecting the XML I saw it was required.
this new request worked:

```
client.service.authenticate(
                MYWSHeader={'key1':'','key2':''}
                username=self.user,
                password=self.password,
            )
```